# What is the meaning of "Шню"?

Tags: значения, глаголы

I am quite a beginner, and I am studying Russian language by myself.
Currently I am trying to learn by translating some fairy tale from Народные русские сказки, by Афанасьев.

There is this one fairy tale in which a fox says

> «Шню, шню, бычок, соломенный бочок! Сани чужие, хомут не свой, погоняй — не стой!»

**What does "шню" mean?**

By the way, if you could tell me also the correct translation of the whole sentence, it would be great!

If anyone is interested, the title of the fairy tale is "За лапоток — курочку, за курочку — гусочку"

Comment: It's probably some form of onomatopoeia, close to “хрю-хрю” or “нюх-нюх”.

Comment: I am a native russian, but i have never faced with this word and I don't know it's meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never come across this interjection/exclamation, but judging by the context it's a word of spurring/speeding a draft animal much like **giddyup, hyah, hait** etc.

The most known such Russian word is **Но!** which is / used to be said to spur a horse.

<sup>Of course that's a matter of personal taste, but i wouldn't start learning English from Shakespear or Chinese from Book of Songs, just because they're written in an archaic (or dialectal) language. I believe a more natural course would be the opposite - from modern and standard language to archaic and dialectal</sup>

Comment: It can also be just a kind of a poem/song metric filler, like _ай, люли_ or _Hickory Dickory Dock_.

Comment: Thank you! I will accept the answer soon. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think that the majority of the stories in that book are fairly simple to understand and not so archaic in the lexicon (this one is one of the exceptions).